# Zombie goroutines in Go

Tags: go, goroutine

I was always wondering how could a goroutine in Go get killed until i recently watched *[A Channel Compendium](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SmoM1InWXr0#t=7m6s)* by John Graham-Cumming at GoPherCon and realized that its as simple as having a return statement inside the code executed by goroutines. So the same goes for closures right? Shouldn't we always use return statements inside closures so every goroutine executing a closure terminates at some point? What are the disadvantages of having zombie goroutines in your system and how do they get terminated?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Yes, the *function* has to return to kill a Goroutine, but that doesn't entail an explicit return statement.

Comment: The cost of pinned closures is only at most the size of the closed-over variables, and any heap memory that those variables are pointing to. If you're just closing over a few ints, for example, then the cost will be negligible compared to the (at least) 4kb goroutine stack held open by the zombie goroutine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per Jsor's comment, a function must return to end a goroutine, but that can happen if it reaches the end of the function even if there isn't an explicit `return` statement.

If a goroutine never returns (for example because it contains an infinite `for {}` with no `break`s or `return`s) and is no longer doing useful work then it is basically a memory leak; it will never get terminated, and it simply sits and chews up resources until your program ends.

For more details, read the thread at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/uiySuH8_3Y4

Comment: If you are unfortunate to let a goroutine run freely, consuming CPU but doing nothing useful, this is clearly an unwanted situation and needs to be fixed. Furthermore, if you have more than one goroutine engaging in communications together but effectively thrashing around an infinite `for{}` loop, you have a [**livelock**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock#Livelock) situation. Livelocks are like deadlocks in that both are caused by a fault in the design and both cause the program to malfunction.